# Cannot import spacy -Jupyter python 3 notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, spacy

### I am trying to create a jupyter notebook for an NLP project and I am failing to import `spacy`. I get the error below

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-728c089140d2> in <module>
      6 import numpy as np
      7 import re
----> 8 import spacy
      9 
     10 # libraries for visualization

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'
```

May anyone help with suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Conda:

```
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} spacy
```

Otherwise, use pip:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install spacy
```

Comment: @NomsaMwayenga Awesome! Don't forget to upvote and accept it as the answer :)